# What kind of switch is this surface mount component with no actuator?

Tags: switches, identification, components

One way I am learning about electronics is to try to analyze the function of random small circuit boards that I come across.  I found a device with a component labeled SW2, so likely it’s a switch.  It’s the grey cylindrical component with gold endcaps in the attached picture.

I don’t understand how it can function as it appears to have no visible way to alter the switch setting. Is it some kind of reed switch? Has it been mislabeled and really it is something else?

[image: closeup of electronic component]

Comment: What is the device this came from? Could be a reed switch. Could be a tilt switch.

Comment: Not entirely sure on the device it came from.  I’m beginning to think it is some sort of security device like you see attached to expensive items.  It has a coil around a bar magnet labeled TAG .. so RF tag?  Also has fairly loud sound transducer on it. Also an IR emitter and IR receiver.   So tilt switch sounds likely .. I’ll research those to see how to test it.

Comment: I think that it is either a tilt switch or a vibration switch.  Connect a fast-responding continuity meter or LED / battery / resistor to the end caps and see what happens as you move the board around.

Comment: Confirmed. It is a vibration switch.  Thanks to @DwayneReid for the test method.

Comment: @MOSFET I’ve been googling and now believe that it is a Pataco security product.  The shape of the board and plastic piece it was still attached to seem to suggest it’s one of their “turtle” products.   I found it in a HomeDepot & Staples parking lot.  Maybe somebody stole something and smashed it while on the run? https://www.pataco.swiss/our-products/?lang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a vibration switch similar to [these](https://images.100y.com.tw/pdf_file/50-XXW-2030.pdf):
[image]

Comment: Confirmed. It is a vibration switch. Thanks to @DwayneReid for the test method.

Comment: Is it confirmed to have the closed-at-rest function? Or does it close when tapped?

Comment: Yes. Confirmed to have the closed-at-rest function.